# Is DC demotion affecting RDP connections?

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-controller, rdp, windows-terminal-services

Our Terminal Services Server is Win 2003 running Microsoft RDP 5.2. The RDP connections from outside of the network used to be smooth but they are now choppy and unreliable because the user is regularly interrupted by timeouts irrespective of what OS they are running. This has been happening for about 6 weeks or so .... around about the time that the server was demoted as a DC. Coincidence? No settings were changed on the Terminal Services Server. I feel the router is at fault but could it be related to the DC demotion?

Comment: I don't see how it could be related.

Comment: Ok thanks joe. If nothing comes in add No for an answer.

Comment: It's a networking issue, almost definitely.

Comment: please do continue SpacemanSpiff

Comment: Sorry to chime in here on your question... but I am contemplating demoting my 2003 AD, which is also a Terminal Server. Did your demotion affect the user accounts, user folders and in general, the RDP experience? I am a bit scekptical as all the accounts are now in "AD Users and Computers", will that be "moved" to normal Users and Groups? And everything function normally? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, the poor rdp connection was not related to dc demotion. The root cause was due to the DSL connection.